# R series by terminal A in a potentiometer

Tags: resistance, potentiometer

I have a question to clarify about potentiometers. Maybe the question is something silly or obvious, but I would like clarification because I'm not so sure about it and I need to be so as not to miss my calculations. I'm using a retractable spring sensor that works like a potentiometer. Well, it is a potentiometer. So I will explain the case as if it just was a potentiometer to avoid a mess.
If a potentiometer is something like this:
[image]

If A node, which is the one that is not ground and usually goes to V++, is connected to another R in series with the source voltage, like this:

[image]

Is it suppossed that W has RW = R26 + Rpot? That is, taking as an example the case where Rpot is maximum - for this case: 5K -, What is there in  W terminal? Has it Rpot = 1M + 5K? or does it represent that W stills having only RW = 5K when I connect W node to another part of circuit?

[image]

Which one will be the correct equivalent circuit? how Rpot is really connected? 1 or 2 option?

[image]

If someone could explain me how to translate this configuration it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What is there in W terminal?* - do you mean, what is the effective resistance from the W terminal to ground taking into account the presense of R26. Or do you mean what is the voltage at W?

Comment: @Andyaka I mean, the effective Resistance from W taking into account R26. What is there after W terminal is another R that goes to ground. I will edit my post and paste a new pict with the complete connection.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, first circuit picture is correct when RWB is 0Ohms and RWA = 5Kohms, this happens when the position has reached the maximum distance. But when distance is minimum, the RWA = 0Ohms. This means the second circuit is wrong. W will be connected to ground. So R1 will have no effect. Rpot must be divided (or separated) into 2 resistences with complementary values: RWA + RWB = Rpot.
How I found it is through finding the correct equivalent circuit and calculating Vout. After this I did some position tests and the both values, experimental and theoretical matches.

[image]

Req = R9 + RBW + (RWA||R26) = Req1 + Req2

Req1 = R9 + RBW

Req2 = RWA||R26

So Vout = Vin·[Req2/(Req2 + Req1)]

When RWA = 0Ohm --> Vout = 0V.

When RWB = 0Ohms --> Vout = Vin · 4975/(4975+1000) = 9.99V